# Execute FIFO using Verilog on Nexys4 DDR board

Tags: verilog

[Simulation output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryLxN.jpg)

Hello, please help me with this problem. ..with the code given below buff_mem.v

Everything works fine till simulation but problem arises when I try to program it on board (Nexys4 DDR). It takes just one push and one pop to show full and empty flags while I want to write data till its depth (i.e till fifo_counter = f).
I want to write multiple data till its depth (full) and then read till its empty. ..which doesn't happen. Is it problem with pushbutton taking multiple writes' and reads' with one press or something I'm not aware ??? PLIZ help me with the code !!!

```
`define BUF_WIDTH 4    
`define BUF_SIZE ( 1<<`BUF_WIDTH )
module buff_mem( clk, rst, wr_en, rd_en, buf_in, buf_out, buf_empty, buf_full, fifo_counter );
input                 rst, clk, wr_en, rd_en;   
input [7:0]           buf_in;                   
output[7:0]           buf_out;                  
output                buf_empty, buf_full;      
output[(`BUF_WIDTH - 1):0] fifo_counter;             

reg[7:0]              buf_out;
reg                   buf_empty, buf_full;
reg[(`BUF_WIDTH - 1):0]  fifo_counter;
reg[(`BUF_WIDTH - 1):0]  rd_ptr, wr_ptr;        // pointer to read and write addresses  
reg[7:0] buf_mem [`BUF_SIZE - 1 : 0];           // RAM  
always @(fifo_counter)
begin
   buf_empty = (fifo_counter==0);
   buf_full = (fifo_counter==(`BUF_SIZE - 1));
end

always @(posedge clk or posedge rst)
begin
   if( rst )
       fifo_counter <= 0;
   else if( (!buf_full && wr_en) && ( !buf_empty && rd_en ) )
       fifo_counter <= fifo_counter;
   else if( !buf_full && wr_en )
       fifo_counter <= fifo_counter + 1;
   else if( !buf_empty && rd_en )
       fifo_counter <= fifo_counter - 1;  
   else
      fifo_counter <= fifo_counter;
end

always @( posedge clk or posedge rst)       //read
begin
   if( rst )
      buf_out <= 0;
   else
   begin
      if( rd_en && !buf_empty )
         buf_out <= buf_mem[rd_ptr];
      else
         buf_out <= buf_out;
   end
end

always @(posedge clk)                   //write
begin
   if( wr_en && !buf_full )
      buf_mem[ wr_ptr ] <= buf_in;
   else
      buf_mem[ wr_ptr ] <= buf_mem[ wr_ptr ];
end

always@(posedge clk or posedge rst)     //handling rd_ptr & wr_ptr
begin
   if( rst )
   begin
      wr_ptr <= 0;
      rd_ptr <= 0;
   end
   else
   begin
      if( !buf_full && wr_en )    wr_ptr <= wr_ptr + 1;
        else  wr_ptr <= wr_ptr;
      if( !buf_empty && rd_en )   rd_ptr <= rd_ptr + 1;
        else rd_ptr <= rd_ptr;
   end
end
endmodule
```

Here's the constraint file for it -

```
## Clock signal
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN E3    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { clk }]; #IO_L12P_T1_MRCC_35 Sch=clk100mhz

##Switches
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN J15   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { wr_en }]; #IO_L24N_T3_RS0_15 Sch=sw[0]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN L16   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { rd_en }]; #IO_L3N_T0_DQS_EMCCLK_14 Sch=sw[1]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN M13   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { buf_in[0] }]; #IO_L6N_T0_D08_VREF_14 Sch=sw[2]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN R15   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { buf_in[1] }]; #IO_L13N_T2_MRCC_14 Sch=sw[3]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN R17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { buf_in[2] }]; #IO_L12N_T1_MRCC_14 Sch=sw[4]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN T18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { buf_in[3] }]; #IO_L7N_T1_D10_14 Sch=sw[5]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN U18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { buf_in[4] }]; #IO_L17N_T2_A13_D29_14 Sch=sw[6]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN R13   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { buf_in[5] }]; #IO_L5N_T0_D07_14 Sch=sw[7]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN T8    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS18 } [get_ports { buf_in[6] }]; #IO_L24N_T3_34 Sch=sw[8]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN U8    IOSTANDARD LVCMOS18 } [get_ports { buf_in[7] }]; #IO_25_34 Sch=sw[9]

## LEDs
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN H17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { buf_empty }]; #IO_L18P_T2_A24_15 Sch=led[0]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN K15   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { buf_full }]; #IO_L24P_T3_RS1_15 Sch=led[1]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN J13   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { buf_out[0] }]; #IO_L17N_T2_A25_15 Sch=led[2]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN N14   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { buf_out[1] }]; #IO_L8P_T1_D11_14 Sch=led[3]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN R18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { buf_out[2] }]; #IO_L7P_T1_D09_14 Sch=led[4]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN V17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { buf_out[3] }]; #IO_L18N_T2_A11_D27_14 Sch=led[5]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN U17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { buf_out[4] }]; #IO_L17P_T2_A14_D30_14 Sch=led[6]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN U16   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { buf_out[5] }]; #IO_L18P_T2_A12_D28_14 Sch=led[7]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN V16   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { buf_out[6] }]; #IO_L16N_T2_A15_D31_14 Sch=led[8]
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN T15   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { buf_out[7] }]; #IO_L14N_T2_SRCC_14 Sch=led[9]

##Buttons
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN N17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { rst }]; #IO_L9P_T1_DQS_14 Sch=btnc
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN M18   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { wr_en }]; #IO_L4N_T0_D05_14 Sch=btnu
set_property -dict { PACKAGE_PIN P17   IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 } [get_ports { rd_en }]; #IO_L12P_T1_MRCC_14 Sch=btnl
```

Answer (score 0):

The push buttons need a debouncer circuit. [Here](http://www.fpga4fun.com/Debouncer2.html) is an example in Verilog, however I haven't tried it myself. There should be one instance of this module for each button (e.g. `wr_en`, `rd_en`).

To see what's going on when a button is pushed, `fifo_counter` may be connected to LEDs as well. As far as I see from the [board schematic](https://reference.digilentinc.com/_media/nexys4-ddr:nexys_4_ddr_sch.pdf), there are available LEDs.

```
LED10 -> U14
LED13 -> V14
LED14 -> V12
LED15 -> V11
```